# I get this error in Logcat upon my app startup

Tags: android

> 08-31 21:29:15.263: ERROR/dalvikvm(11799): could not disable core file generation for pid 11799, errno=1

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks!

---

I'm using a non OTA push of Froyo on this phone currently.  I did some checking and apparently there is a bug in early releases of Froyo - Which has already been fixed, but because I'm using a pre-release, I think this is still apparent in the ROM running on the phone.

Below is a boot up error report on my phone from LogCat - my app was uninstalled and not even re-pushed to the phone.  Until I get the official OTA update, this is nothing I can worry about now.

Thank You!

```
09-01 09:57:04.325: ERROR/PackageManager(1262): Package com.motorola.android.FirewallService requires unavailable shared library com.motorola.android.Firewall; failing!
09-01 09:57:23.933: ERROR/MotWifiScan(1262): disableMlbs: NOT disabling because not ON!
09-01 09:57:24.012: ERROR/GlobalUnplugService(1552): plugged = true,mBatteryPlugged=false
09-01 09:57:27.301: ERROR/NetworkStateTracker(1262): net.tcp.buffersize.evdo not found in system properties. Using defaults
09-01 09:57:27.355: ERROR/BluetoothPanService(1262): Received CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
09-01 09:57:27.355: ERROR/BluetoothPanService(1262): Received,CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, TYPE_MOBILE
09-01 09:57:27.355: ERROR/BluetoothPanService(1262): Received, CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, TYPE_MOBILE, isConnected
09-01 09:57:27.355: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(1262): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
09-01 09:57:27.355: ERROR/dalvikvm(1613): could not disable core file generation for pid 1613, errno=1
09-01 09:57:28.027: ERROR/extdisp(1622): tvout_init: dlopen error
09-01 09:57:28.027: ERROR/extdisp(1622): nativeInit: tvout_init error!
09-01 09:57:31.449: ERROR/DSP(1675): fResult.getData() : null
09-01 09:57:32.129: ERROR/dalvikvm(1730): could not disable core file generation for pid 1730, errno=1
09-01 09:57:33.512: ERROR/NetworkStateTracker(1262): net.tcp.buffersize.evdo not found in system properties. Using defaults
09-01 09:57:33.597: ERROR/BluetoothPanService(1262): Received CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
09-01 09:57:33.605: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(1262): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
09-01 09:57:33.980: ERROR/GlobalUnplugService(1552): plugged = true,mBatteryPlugged=true
09-01 09:57:34.465: ERROR/dalvikvm(1793): could not disable core file generation for pid 1793, errno=1
09-01 09:57:34.512: ERROR/GlobalUnplugService(1552): plugged = true,mBatteryPlugged=true
09-01 09:57:38.457: ERROR/dalvikvm(1793): Could not find class 'android.net.NetworkConnectivityListener', referenced from method com.handcent.sms.transaction.TransactionService.onCreate
09-01 09:57:38.457: ERROR/dalvikvm(1793): Could not find class 'android.net.NetworkConnectivityListener', referenced from method com.handcent.sms.transaction.TransactionService.onDestroy
09-01 09:57:38.465: ERROR/dalvikvm(1793): Could not find class 'android.net.NetworkConnectivityListener', referenced from method com.handcent.sms.transaction.ah.handleMessage
09-01 09:57:39.137: ERROR/WeatherUtil(1419): No location provider
09-01 09:57:44.738: ERROR/GlobalUnplugService(1552): plugged = true,mBatteryPlugged=true
09-01 09:57:46.418: ERROR/Preferences(1893):   recovered user & security token 
09-01 09:57:47.090: ERROR/GlobalUnplugService(1552): plugged = true,mBatteryPlugged=true
09-01 09:57:47.379: ERROR/dalvikvm(1906): could not disable core file generation for pid 1906, errno=1
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534): Unable to decode bitmap 
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No icons fit this description
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:143)
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:608)
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:469)
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:304)
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.util.ui.BitmapUtil.fetchBitmapWithAdjustedDimensions(BitmapUtil.java:50)
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.contacts.cache.SourceCache.getSourceIcon(SourceCache.java:793)
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.contacts.cache.SourceCache.access$000(SourceCache.java:41)
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.contacts.cache.SourceCache$2.run(SourceCache.java:744)
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
09-01 09:57:49.785: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-01 09:58:02.113: ERROR/TwitterDataSync(1860): Token not found.
09-01 09:58:17.074: ERROR/TalkProvider(1429): replaceContactWithContactId: contactId==0!!! jeff@trystfall.com, acct=1
09-01 09:58:17.098: ERROR/TalkProvider(1429): insert presence failed for account=1 username=jeff@trystfall.com client_type=0 status= priority=0 mode=5
09-01 09:58:17.199: ERROR/TalkProvider(1429): replaceContactWithContactId: contactId==0!!! jeff@trystfall.com, acct=1
09-01 09:58:17.238: ERROR/TalkProvider(1429): insert presence failed for account=1 username=jeff@trystfall.com client_type=0 status= priority=0 mode=5
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534): Unable to decode bitmap 
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No icons fit this description
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:143)
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:608)
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:469)
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:304)
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.util.ui.BitmapUtil.fetchBitmapWithAdjustedDimensions(BitmapUtil.java:50)
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.contacts.cache.SourceCache.getSourceIcon(SourceCache.java:793)
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.contacts.cache.SourceCache.access$000(SourceCache.java:41)
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.contacts.cache.SourceCache$2.run(SourceCache.java:744)
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
09-01 09:58:22.472: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534): Unable to decode bitmap 
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No icons fit this description
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:143)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:608)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:469)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:304)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.util.ui.BitmapUtil.fetchBitmapWithAdjustedDimensions(BitmapUtil.java:50)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.contacts.cache.SourceCache.getSourceIcon(SourceCache.java:793)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.contacts.cache.SourceCache.access$000(SourceCache.java:41)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at com.motorola.blur.contacts.cache.SourceCache$2.run(SourceCache.java:744)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
09-01 09:58:30.613: ERROR/BitmapUtil(1534):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: Can you add some context on what you are trying to do and if the application worked before you made some changes.  Also try restarting your emulator/phone and pushing the program over again.

Comment: So is this for non-OTA updated Froyo?